# How to move a 3d text to clicked position in A-FRAME?

Tags: javascript, html, positioning, ar.js

I have used the codes as described below. The object moves when I click on a certain position of the screen but on certain points there seems to be huge random gaps between the clicked position and the position of the object than the other points.Also when I change the screen size, the distance between the clicked position and the object changes.

```
const object = document.querySelector('#position');
document.body.addEventListener("click",function(event){
    var x = (event.pageX-window.innerWidth/1.70)/170;
    var y = (event.pageY-window.innerHeight/1.5)/-120;

    const textobject = document.querySelector('a-entity');
    textobject.object3D.position.set(x, y, -7);

    console.log("x:" + x + "px");
    console.log("y:" + y + "px");
```